# Click on an address dynamically populated in robot framework

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework

[image]

I am inputting an address in a text box which dynamically displays an address (powered by google). I need to click the down arrow and hit tab to select an address. I tried Press Key but it did not work. So, I tried the below extended library. So, when in my test case, i call this in settings, Library  ExtendedSelenium.py and in the Test case section, I called press_down_arrow. Still it does not press the down arrow. Am I doing wrong?  Do I need to supply any ID or values? Kindly help

```
# ExtendedSelenium.py
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class ExtendedSelenium(SeleniumLibrary):

def __init__(self):
    super(ExtendedSelenium, self).__init__()

def press_down_arrow(self):
    """ Emulates action "press down arrow on keyboard".
    """
    ActionChains(self._current_browser()).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.NULL).perform()
```

Comment: You probably need to at least first set the focus to that element, unless your app lets you press the down arrow no matter which widget has focus.

Comment: I tried a lot but all in vain. Could not press a down arrow.

Comment: You tried a lot of _what_? Your code doesn't show you giving the widget focus.